# Why does writing to memory take longer than reading in GPU?

Tags: optimization, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

Here is part of my code where I update some values and write it to another part of my memory

```
__kernel void update(
        __global float4 *f,
        __global float4 *p,
        const unsigned int n,
        __local float4 *sharedP){

        float4 val = (float4)(0.f,0.f,0.f,0.f);

        size_t lID = get_local_id(0);
        size_t gID = get_global_id(0);

        if(gID < n){
            float4 p1 = p[gID];
            for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i){
                if(i!=gID){
                    float4 p2 = p1 - p[i];
                    //Some other calculations to finally update 'val' 
                }
            }
            f[gID] = val;
         }
}
```

Here each thread reads from the global memory n+1 times, but writes back only once.(My initial thought was that, the bottleneck was due repeated call to the global memory, hence I had made some changes to copy a block of data into the shared memory, swap it and other things. Even this did not improve the performance a lot). However later I found that the bottleneck is due to `f[gID] = val;`. For example when the kernel is run `200` times with `n = 8192`, it takes `3.5s`; but if I comment out `f[gID] = val;` it takes only `0.05s`.

Code for other method

```
__kernel void update(
        __global float4 *f,
        __global float4 *p,
        const unsigned int n,
        __local float4 *sharedP){

        float4 val = (float4)(0.f,0.f,0.f,0.f);

        size_t lID = get_local_id(0);
        size_t gID = get_global_id(0);

        if(gID < n){
            sharedP[lID] = p[gID];
            barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
            float4 p1 = sharedP[lID];

            //To prevent i!=gID of other method
            for(size_t i = 0; i < get_local_size(0);; ++i){
                if(lID!=i){
                    float4 p2 = p1 - sharedP[i];
                    //Some other calculations to update 'val' at 0
                }
            }

            for(size_t block = 1; block < (size_t)(get_global_size(0)/get_local_size(0)); ++block){
                size_t idx = lID + (get_group_id(0) + block ) * get_local_size(0);

                if( idx >= n)
                    idx -= n;

                sharedP[lID] = p[idx];
                barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
                for(size_t i = 0; i < get_local_size(0); ++i){
                    float4 p = p1 - sharedP[i];
                    //Some other calculations to update 'val'
                }   
                f[gID] = val;
            }
        }
}
```

So how is writing to memory causing it to slow down so much and why is using shared memory not providing a significant performance increase?

Comment: Not a GPU guy, but I can guess that when you write to memory, the compiler cannot make any assumptions about memory access timing and must setup locks and such.

Comment: Hmmm,,, But I have another kernel, that does ONLY copying(for example form p to f[both in device memory]) , and it takes much lesser time.

Comment: What happens if you remove that shared var and setup a local, then mark `*p` as constant?  Less vars and maybe it can use uniforms better.  Do you have a way of having the GPU directly tell you why you are stalling and what is taking the time?  Also, be sure this is marked as release code too...

Comment: Also for 2nd example, if you remove the `f[gID]` write but leave the shared write, it still is much faster?

Comment: Final thought, if you remove the `f[gID]` write in the first example, there is no affect in the code at all and the system is probably not doing any work at all.  Hence the big savings.

Comment: I do not see any difference, by marking it as a constant and removing the shared memory. For both codes if I remove `f[gID]` it performs better. My only profiling tool is std::cout

Comment: I tried again with optimizations disabled using `-cl-opt-disable`, now both variants took 33 seconds; so I tried again with removing the for and just writing it to f[gID], it took 0.007s. You were right, Thanks!!!